# Memory Leaks for typedef struct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I m trying to remove memory leaks. Below is my code.

```
currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

CFTimeZoneRef currentTimeZone = CFTimeZoneCopyDefault();

todaysDate = CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate(currentTime, currentTimeZone);


[currentTimeZone release];
currentTimeZone = nil;
```

Warning:::/myclass.m:87: warning: invalid receiver type 'CFTimeZoneRef'

how to release memory for typedef const struct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `CFxxxCopyxxx` you should use `CFRelease`.

```
CFRelease(currentTimeZone);
```

**Edit:**

There are [CoreFoundation](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?TollFreeBridged) classes that are [Toll-Free bridged](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?TollFreeBridging) and your original statement was not leaking but just needed a cast. I would still recommend using `CFRelease` since you were working directly with CoreFoundation.

```
[(NSTimeZone*)currentTimeZone release];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> If you own an object, it is your responsibility to relinquish
>   ownership (using CFRelease) when you have finished with it.

Comment: He understood that he needed to release it, the problem was that he didn't know how to release it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a CoreFoundation call, so instead of using Cocoa's `release`, you will want to call:

```
CFRelease( currentTimeZone);
```

in order to release the copied data.

Answer (score 0):

try relesing addressBook after allPeople

CFRelease(allPeople);
    CFRelease(addressBook);

This worked for me.